# how do I do compare between the value comes from methods and values in queryset? [django]

Tags: django

if I need to make a comparison between two values. the first value comes from **(POST method)** and the second value comes from **list of queryset** in the database of Django.
for instance, 
answer = request.POST['answer']
suppose we have a class called **(Result)**, in this case, **(The Result)** have some values in the list as a **(queryset)** that we need to compare with **(answer)**. 
1 - so, how we do this comparison if it is true?
2 - also, if that way not the correct way then what is the alternative way to make something like that?
3 - how can I do a comparison with string into a list of queryset, for instance, 
if answer in Result.objects.all()

Comment: That's a messy description. It's not obvious what you mean by "compare" and also you cant compare string directly with queryset. What's your model and what exactly you want to compare?

Comment: I mean comparison or search in queryset just like when I do a search with string by (if condition) in python I can write: if string in list that's what I mean exactly. in this case, the answer will give me True or False.
sorry, maybe I cannot determine the question exactly but I have no idea about the question of what can contain exactly but now I defined the question. so, I wish if I get an answer.@Charnel

Comment: It seems that you're looking for something like this `Result.objects.filter(field_you_are_checking_occurrence=answer_from_your_request)` or `answer in Result.objects.filter(some_filtering_conditions).values_list('field_name', flat=True)`